# Реализация считывания данных с Excel файла и запись в виде таблицы на сайте

Tags: python, django

Необходимо загрузить Excel файл и считать все данные, находящиеся в нём, после чего записать их в таблицу на сайте с помощью Django. Хотелось бы получить наводку на решение. Не уверен, реализуемо ли это с помощью данного фреймворка, так что если есть другие Python-фреймворки для выполнения данной работы - с удовольствием попробую.

Comment: Начните с чтения Excel (openpyxl вам в помощь). Потом обновите вопрос с примером кода, если будут какие-то проблемы, а если нет, то сразу делайте ответ с примером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала прочитайте Эксель-файл:

```
import xlrd #библиотека для чтения экселек
exc_dict = {} #словарь для записи данных из экселя, можно использовать другой массив
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'Путь к файлу Эксель.xlsx') #подключаем файл эксель
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0) #лист в книге эксель по индексу, т.е. 0 - это первый лист книги
for i in range(sh.nrows):
    x = sh.row_values(i) #читаем циклом лист экселя построчно, получаем кортеж строки эксель
    if i not in exc_dict:
        exc_dict[i] = x #записываем строки в словарь, где ключ - номер строки, значение - кортеж строки
```

Затем создайте модель в файле `models.py`, в которой вы будете хранить свои данные.
В файле `views.py` пропишите загрузку сохраненных выше данных в ваш html-шаблон.
В html-шаблоне с помощью шаблонизатора выведите нужные динамические данные в табличных тегах (`<table>, <tr>, <td>`).

Шаги по работе с Django здесь нет смысла расписывать, ибо очень длинно выйдет. Можете посмотреть тут: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/